# Can we configure ADF to copy each fileShare to another account?connect to (//storageAccount/) not (//Storageaccount/FileShare)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

**I want to copy all my file shares to another account**

Things that I have tried

1. I have tried using storage Explorer but this has size limitations
2. Azcopy this will fail abruptly with some errors
3. ADF this works but I need to do this for every fileshare

   I wanted to know can I get the list of fileshares in ADF and feed it to for-each and perform the copy ?

I am not sure how to achieve or use foreach to get fileshares in  data factory

I feel that there is no way to get connected to storage account without specifying the fileShare, If I give the name of file share then , I can access only content inside it, I am trying to figure out a way to copy all file share in storage account, that is to connect to //storageacount/ not //storageaccount/FileShare

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know can I get the list of fileshares in ADF and feed it
>   to for-each and perform the copy ?

If you select [recursive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-file-storage#azure-file-storage-as-source) as true,the files and sub-files will be all copied into new locations.

[image]

If you do want to get list of fileshares, you could use [Get Metadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) and [ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity).

1.Get folder list:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#get-a-folders-metadata

2.Loop the output of Get Metadata Activity: `@activity('Get Metadata1').output`

Comment: Thanks for the info , but there is no way to get connected to storage account without specifying the fileShare, If I give the name of file share then , I can access only content inside it, I am trying to figure out a way to copy all file share in storage account, that is to connect to  //storageacount/  not //storageaccount/FileShare.